# Unit test for customer ActionFilterAttribute failed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-core

The project is aspnet core 2.1 and i use customer ActionFilterAttribute as belows:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        { 
            var descriptor = context.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;
            if (descriptor != null)
            {
                foreach (var parameter in descriptor.MethodInfo.GetParameters())
                {
                    object args = null;
                    if (context.ActionArguments.ContainsKey(parameter.Name))
                    {
                        args = context.ActionArguments[parameter.Name];
                    }

                    ValidateAttributes(parameter, args, context.ModelState);
                }
            }

            if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);
            }
        }
```

and now I add a unit test code to test the filter,

```
[TestMethod]
        public void ValidateModelAttributes_SetsResultToBadRequest_IfModelIsInvalid()
        {
            var validationFilter = new ValidateModelStateAttribute();
            var modelState = new ModelStateDictionary();
            modelState.AddModelError("name", "invalid");
            var actionDescriptor = new ActionDescriptor();

            var actionContext = new ActionContext(
                Mock.Of<HttpContext>(),
                Mock.Of<RouteData>(),
                Mock.Of<ActionDescriptor>(),
                modelState
            );

            var actionExecutingContext = new ActionExecutingContext(
                actionContext,
                new List<IFilterMetadata>(),
                new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "1", "1" } },
                Mock.Of<Controller>()
            );

            validationFilter.OnActionExecuting(actionExecutingContext);

            Assert.IsNotNull(actionExecutingContext.Result);
        }
```

but the descriptor always return null:

```
var descriptor = context.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;
```

Can you help me to fix the unit test code?

Comment: `but the descriptor always return null`, that is because in the test a `Mock.Of<ActionDescriptor>()` which will be a `ActionDescriptor` but the subject under test casts to `ControllerActionDescriptor`, which the mock is not, and thus null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but the descriptor always return null`,

that is because in the test a `Mock.Of<ActionDescriptor>()` which will be a `ActionDescriptor` is used, but the subject under test casts to `ControllerActionDescriptor`, which the mock is not, and thus null.

Use the appropriate mock

```
//...omitted for brevity

var actionContext = new ActionContext(
    Mock.Of<HttpContext>(),
    Mock.Of<RouteData>(),
    Mock.Of<ControllerActionDescriptor>(),
    modelState
);

//...omitted for brevity
```

You would still need to setup the mock so that the accessed members behave as expected when exercising the test